# Text Analyzer not able to output proper information from file

Tags: java, macos

Currently I'm trying to code a document that is able to read the number of sentences in a document as well as the characters, words, and declarations within the document. I'm using mac OSX at the moment and am stuck trying to get the file to output the proper information. Are there special permissions that need to be made within the mac environment?

Update:

I've found a temporary work around for the moment. I discovered the original file has different permission settings and basically copy and pasted the text within the file into a new one entirely. Seems that if permissions are not set properly for the file then it will not be able to read into the file, yet still state the file is there.

Comment: Those double slashes ("//") in the file name - perhaps not harmful, but why? Never heard about this being required anywhere.

Comment: Have you checked that the file isn't size 0 when you put it onto your mac?  Could have been an issue when copying it over - Sanity check

Comment: This program *never* ran on *any* system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the next line or token is read into

```
String token = reader.next();
```

the code analyzing this string should not use `str`.

And the initialization of x and y must be moved into the read loop.

Why duplicate the pass through the token? But a space will not be stored in a token, as it acts as a delimiter.